# How to select this element (in Python)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to get a selector on this `action-button` class using Selenium in Python, but through using a Javascript Document QuerySelector. That means executing some js code via the WebDriver, which looks something like this:

```
    printBtnlast = driver.execute_script(
                "return document.querySelector('print-preview-app')...('controls').querySelector({WHAT_TO_DO_HERE?})"
    )
```

(abridged with '...' to show the main idea)

So far I have tried the query:
`'cr-button[class='action-button']'`, which surprisingly gives a `Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list`.

What can I place in **{WHAT_TO_DO_HERE?}** in order to access the `action-button` in the image below?

[image: Final Div]

Comment: I apologize @cruisepandey, I should have followed up on the last question. Your help was indispensable on my prior issue. There was one problem with your code, but I modified it so that all that's left is this final issue. After making this change I have accepted the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query Selector` syntax is a little bit different than `XPath` syntax. You can use `CSS Selectors` to locate an element. One way to find the button:

```js
querySelector("cr-button.action-button")
```

I don't have access to the page since you didn't provide, but it may be the case that there are more than one elements with the given path. Then other solution might be:

```js
querySelector("div.controls > cr-button.action-button")
```

The query you tried may give an error due to the quotation marks. You can try this:

```js
'cr-button[class="action-button"]'
```

This should work:

```py
printBtnlast = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.controls > .action-button')")
```

Comment: Your last point got me to the right answer:  `'cr-button[class="action-button"]'` does not work for me because of the "" that wrap the entire JS statement. But what I was able to do was use: `'cr-button[class=\"action-button\"]'`  And this worked.

Answer (score 1):

for this

```
  printBtnlast = driver.execute_script(
                "return document.querySelector('print-preview-app')...('controls').querySelector({WHAT_TO_DO_HERE?})"
    )
```

You can try this :

```
printBtnlast = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('div.controls > cr-button.action-button')")
```

or

```
printBtnlast = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('cr-button.action-button')")
```

Comment: Just tried this, it gives me `javascript error: Unexpected token '.'`

Comment: Just got my answer from @Muhteva, but just curious, what is the '>' operator doing in your question?

Comment: '>' finds the immediate children rather than looking recursively.